# Orika not able to map when the application is running on Jetty

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I am using Orika to map between two java objects. When I run junit tests it works fine - the objects are mapped correctly, but when I execute the code running on jetty I get this exception:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Loracle/dms/console/DMSConsole;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at com.carrotsearch.sizeof.RamUsageEstimator.createCacheEntry(RamUsageEstimator.java:568) ~[java-sizeof-0.0.4.jar:na]
at com.carrotsearch.sizeof.RamUsageEstimator.measureSizeOf(RamUsageEstimator.java:532) ~[java-sizeof-0.0.4.jar:na]
at com.carrotsearch.sizeof.RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(RamUsageEstimator.java:380) ~[java-sizeof-0.0.4.jar:na]
at com.carrotsearch.sizeof.RamUsageEstimator.sizeOfAll(RamUsageEstimator.java:361) ~[java-sizeof-0.0.4.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.StateReporter.humanReadableSizeInMemory(StateReporter.java:48) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.reportCurrentState(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1547) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.StateReporter.reportCurrentState(StateReporter.java:33) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ExceptionUtility.decorate(ExceptionUtility.java:65) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.resolveMappingStrategy(MapperFacadeImpl.java:209) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade$BoundStrategyCache.getStrategy(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:259) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:137) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.LocalDate_LocalDate_ObjectFactory1257832766063212584156506661$3.create(LocalDate_LocalDate_ObjectFactory1257832766063212584156506661$3.java) ~[na:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy.getInstance(InstantiateAndUseCustomMapperStrategy.java:55) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:61) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultBoundMapperFacade.map(DefaultBoundMapperFacade.java:137) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_TransactionType_Transaction_Mapper12578333614376$1.mapAtoB(Orika_TransactionType_Transaction_Mapper12578333614376$1.java) ~[na:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:67) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:378) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:367) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:408) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper.map(ConfigurableMapper.java:158) ~[orika-core-1.4.5.jar:na]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dms.console.DMSConsole
...
```

I have attempted to create the mapping code in several ways: (1) extending ConfigurableMapper and (2) setting the facade up (similar to this):

```
MapperFactory factory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
factory.registerClassMap(factory.classMap(Order.class,OrderDTO.class)
  .field("product.state.type.label", "stateLabel")
  .field("product.name", "productName").toClassMap());

MapperFacade mapper = factory.getMapperFacade();
```

The result is always the same, it works fine when I run my junit tests, but it fails when the same code runs as part of a service inside jetty.

I can't seem to understand what DMSConsole has to do with the mapping.

---

**update**

somehow related to joda DateTime mapping, as the project has moved to java.time, this is no longer an issue.

removing this solved the issue:

```
factory.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new PassThroughConverter(DateTime.class));
```

*I still don't see the connection to the exception, so I may be missing something, but no longer an issue.*

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of class visibility, so please, can you disable dump state on exception by using MapperFactory.dumpStateOnException(false) and resend your logs.